# Where to park large amount of money that should be easily accessible?

Tags: united-states, deposits

I will be receiving over 100k to 500k in an insurance settlement and I want to know where I should park this money so I can access it with a card or check. I dont want it tied to the stock market but I do want some decent sort of return. I reside in the USA

Comment: You should provide more context here.  Is this your entire income/money/etc. for a period of time, or is this just 'extra money' you will use for particular purposes?  Are you needing it to pay directly medical bills/etc.?  When you say 'access with card or check' does it have to be instantly available in its entirety, or is it something that you could manage with 5-10k available instantly and the rest after a transfer?

Comment: You are very rarely going to need `100k to 500k` at one go, other than buying a house or gambling. So it makes no sense to park all of it in a single place so that it can be easily accessible. Figure out what is the max you may need in one go and put the remaining where you can earn a return.

Answer (score 2):

A cash management account from an investment firm like Fidelity or Schwab will do that: you can access funds by check or ATM and get a bit of interest. The interest rates are very low. Or you could put it in a money market account and access it by check with a slightly less worse interest rate.

You can pursue higher returns by investing part of the money, but with increasing risk as you seek higher returns. Options include putting some of the money into a short term bond fund, for example.